# " - Package id platforms;android-23: error!

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-note

I wanted to use Android studio 2.3 and my samsung galaxy note5(android 6.0.1) to run simple default `hello world` app on my phone, but I got this error message:

> ```
> All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
> - Package id platforms;android-23
> ```

And after closing the message I see this message in a green box in the bottom of the IDE:

> Instant Run is disabled: Instant Run requires that the Android SDK for
>   the API level of the device you are deploying to is installed. To use
>   Instant Run, open SDK Manager and install the missing platform.

Although program works on my phone and it's installed and I can open and see it in my phone but I like to know why I got this error message and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply because you don't have that package installed. Use the SDK manager  to download them. In the SDK Platforms tab, you must also install at least one version of the Android platform. Each version provides several different packages.

- Open android studio
- Click on Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Go in the SDK Platform tab. To  update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it shows a checkmark.
- To update the selected packages, click **Apply** or **OK**, then agree to any license agreements.

Check also the **compileSDKVersion** in the Gradle(app) file and change it accordingly to the platform you'll download

Comment: It's installed android 7.1.1 by default and I can not install older one! There is no options!

Comment: Android 7.1.1 is android api 25 not 23! You must install android 6.0.1, that's android api 23. Or change compileSDKVersion from 23 to 25 in the Gradle file

Comment: I know, but how should I download the old versions?

Comment: Ok the problem was internet proxy! solved! thanks

Comment: Please give me +1 point!

Comment: Please register an username to the site